# Why / how does this C code compile? and What does it do?

Tags: c, compilation

I have a C code, in which a do loop is started in the first branch of a switch statement. What is weird, is that the rest of the branches of the switch statement are inside the body of the do loop. First, how is it possible that this code compiles? Second, what does it possibly do?

```c
void f(char *x, char *y, int z) {
    int z2 = (z + 7) / 8;
    switch(z % 8) {
        case 0: do { *x++ = *y++;
        case 7: *x++ = *y++;
        case 6: *x++ = *y++;
        case 5: *x++ = *y++;
        case 4: *x++ = *y++;
        case 3: *x++ = *y++;
        case 2: *x++ = *y++;
        case 1: *x++ = *y++;
                } while(--z2 > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: It compile because it's well written, and correct.

Comment: Duffs device. See wikipedia.

Comment: its a memcpy in blocks of 8, taking care of the fact not all "copy lengths" are divisible by 8.

Comment: that said it is not worth using this nowadays. memcpy should that just fine and loopunroling is a common feature in optimizing compilers afaik.

Comment: Yeah - whenever you see something like Duff, or similar, think hard about how difficult it will be to debug...